# navigation , no message receive from trajectory planner!

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
i am running navigation with static map , but when i set a 2Dgoal in rviz robot doesn't move.
In rviz , state of local planner & global planner & planner plan, objects is warning with given info:"no  message receive !"
I am running roswtf and from the output i have realized that the only topics that are not connected are: "/move_base_simple/goal" & "/move_base/cancel"
Any ideas?

thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12407/navigation-,-no-message-receive-from-trajectory-planner!/) by [farshid616](https://answers.ros.org/users/1501/farshid616/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2011-12-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-12-20**:
What do you have specified as the 2D nav goal topic in rviz?

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-12-20**:
What robot are you trying to run and what launch file are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved!
Rviz goal was not connected to /move_base_simple/goal , i have changed topics name to goal , then the problem solved!

---

Originally posted by [farshid616](https://answers.ros.org/users/1501/farshid616/) with karma: 63 on 2011-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0